# Why does abstract model missing few ActiveRecord callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, callback

So that's my abstract model:

```
class AbstractHomeLoan < LoanProduct
  self.abstract_class = true
  after_validation :executed_ok
  after_save :do_some_shit
```

So the first method is executed normally, the second one doesn't. Why? :)

Comment: I just wonder - why are you using abstract class? You know it makes no sense - it can be instantiated anyway?

Comment: Inherited 500 thousand of code... man :)

Comment: Kick your colleague (former Java prog I guess) in the butt then ;)